# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable Bot-Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Написал код для музыкального Discord-бота, но при запуске появляется ошибка. Помогите исправить.

```py
import discord
from yarl import URL
import Config
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'worstaudio/best', 'noplaylist': 'False', 'simulate': 'True', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio'}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}


intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, URL):
   vc = await ctx.messege.author.voice.channel.connect()

with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    if 'https://' in URL:
        info = ydl.extract_info(URL, download=False)
    else:
        info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{URL}", download=False)['entries'][0]

link = info['formats'][0]['URL']

play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source=link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))

client.run(Config.token)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Эльдорадо\Desktop\Python cods\DiscordBotA\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    if 'https://' in URL:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from yarl import URL

...
with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    if 'https://' in URL:
```

Здесь `URL` - импортированный из `yarl` тип, поэтому выходит такая ошибка. Если предполагалось, что `URL` - это параметр функции `async def play(ctx, URL):`, то у вас в коде проблема с отступами, их не хватает. `with ...` у вас получается уже после окончания функции и там ничего не известно об этом её параметре.